# Disconnect processing.run() from source data in QGIS standalone OR How do I remove a file system object from OGR?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am using `processing.run("qgis:rastersampling")` and need a way to disconnect the connection to the corresponding input vector file after each sampling operation. This is what I am thinking of:

```
#settings
QGIS_install="C:/QGIS"
import sys
sys.path.append(QGIS_install+'/apps/qgis-ltr/python/plugins/processing')
import qgis.core as gc
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
gc.QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(QGIS_install, True)
qgs = gc.QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
Processing.initialize()

#loop
for i in range(10000):
    InputVector="C:/vector"+str(i)+".gpkg"
    InputRaster="C:/raster.tif"
    OutputFilePath="C:/output"+str(i)+".gpkg"
    processing.run("qgis:rastersampling", { 'COLUMN_PREFIX' : 'xy', 'INPUT' :  InputVector , 'OUTPUT' : OutputFilePath, 'RASTERCOPY' : InputRaster })

    #***at this point in the loop, I am looking for something that closes/deletes the connection of the input vector file to QGIS***

#some hours of other processing

#exit
qgs.exitQGIS()
```

The problem I am facing is that after several iterations of the loop my RAM is insufficient and Spyder crashes.
Somehow the loop stuffes my memory full of data, and using `.exitGIS()` would make no sense at this part of the script as it a loop, so this is only possible at the very end of the code.

I do not need the vector input anymore for the further calculations.

The `.gpkg-wal` and `.gpkg-shm` files of the opened input vectors accumulate in my folder, so I assume the `processing.run()` leaves connections opened to all vector files once they have been used as Input for the sampling. `gc.QgsProject.instance().removeAllMapLayers()` does not help in this case.

=> I am using Python 3.8 in Spyder 5, working with QGIS 3.16

Edit:
It seems as if it has to do something with the "ogr file system", as I get an error if I try to use the same input vector twice for the rastersampling. The error is:

```
OGR error: A file system object called 'C:/vector1.gpkg' already exists.
```

So the question could be "How do I remove a file system object from OGR?"